# How to modify DOM in an AngularJS application

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, dom, web

I'd like to build a dynamic web layout in which the user is able to rearrange views similar to Eclipse Workbench.

Please consider this example usecase of moving a view to split space with a target view:

[image]

The resulting image of the changed HTML structure:

[image]

This is an example of a rendered layout with its HTML structure:

[image]

I want to use AngularJS' data binding to easily create new views and render the content of the single views including the label of the drag handle.

When the layout information is stored in a model/$scope how can I let AngularJS handle the rendering of the html?

Answer (score -1):

Try use jQuery UI have different event for make this.

- Draggable
- Droppable
- Resizable
- Selectable
- Sortable

And distribute the content with css.

http://jqueryui.com

Comment: How would I use an AngularJS template with databinding if I used jQuery UI to layout the views?

Comment: You can save the distribution of elements in DB.

Comment: Let me try to clarify my problem: I could use jQuery UI to control the drag&drop of a view. However, to rearrange the views I would have to rebuild the html structure (or make DOM changes, please take a look at my html structure example in the OP). How can I build the new html structure while keep the angularjs databinding?